# How to cancel the minibuffer with M-x

Tags: key-bindings, minibuffer

I have M-x (and also my menu key) mapped to the command helm-M-x.

How to write an elisp function or how to configure emacs so that M-x (and the menu key) performs as C-g when the minibuffer is open.

the goal is then to make M-x (and the menu key) a toggle on/off feature.

Comment: I didn't even know that existed. I assume this is disabled by default. So let's say I don't need this feature. Now why do I want this : I guess it feels natural to open and "close" something with the same button. and I find myself too often trying to C-g (which I don't find ergonomic).

Comment: Good answer. And thanks for putting that motivation in the question itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For reasons @Drew pointed out, this is not necessarily a good idea. However, if you really want to do it, you can simply bind `exit-minibuffer` to <kbd>M-x</kbd> in the `minibuffer-local-map` which is the keymap used when in the minibuffer.

You can find information on minibuffer key maps here: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Minibuffer-Maps.html

```lisp
(define-key minibuffer-local-map (kbd "M-x") 'exit-minibuffer)
```

Comment: By the way, is there a symbol (variable/function) to use to know if the mini buffer is currently open or not ? (sorry but I'm really a beginner with emacs)

Comment: OP: Function `active-minibuffer-window`.